# how to change the format of the “person or group” column

Tags: column, calculated-column

In my document set (Sharepoint 2010) I have a column with type of “person or group” which I can add the name of some users to it.

The format of the names is like this: firsName1 Surname1; firstNmae2 Surname2;

However I need to change the name format in this way: Surname1, firstName and Surname2, firstNmae2

Is it possible to use calculated column to convert this column to this format? Or maybe by the use of workflows!

what are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a workflow to do it.  You load the values into a workflow variable, do your string manipulations and then store then back in a text field (not a people picker field).

You can not use the Calculated field with People column.